# Mandatory to create Junction object?

Tags: lookup, relationships, junction-object

I have attached a screenshot of the schema. I have order, order_lines and shipment_lines related as in the following picture...
[image]

Is it mandatory to create a **junction object** to get shipment lines for a particular order line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why Shipment lines is related to Order if the Shipment is related to the order (grandparent). A Shipment line item would seem to be a junction between Shipment and Order Line Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing objects and relationships e.g. like this:

```
select Id, ...
from ShipmentLine__c
where Shipment__c in (select Shipment__c from OrderLines__c where Id = :orderLineId)
order by ...
```

so in general no you do not need to introduce another relationship/junction object.

Here is a good article on the subject of [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com).

Comment: This looks gr8! I wanted to have a field in ShipmentLines__c to display corresponding OrderLines__c. T think I will have to write a trigger to retrieve that field. Am I going the right direction?

Comment: @MnZ Yeah if you are trying to have a direct link from a S hipmentLines__c to an OrderLines__c you'll need to put the logic in several triggers.